# How to create Java JKS file from GoDaddy SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, microservices, self-contained

I bought an SSL certificate in GoDaddy. I need to use it to start my Spark Java self-contained server through a secure connection. According to the documentation in http://sparkjava.com/documentation#examples-and-faq, I need to do the following:

```
String keyStoreLocation = "deploy/keystore.jks";
String keyStorePassword = "password";
secure(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, null, null);
```

But when I download the certificate from GoDaddy I got the files:

```
11111.pem
11111.crt
bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

What do I need to do to convert these files is something compatible to use as the first parameter of  `secure(keyStoreLocation, keyStorePassword, null, null);`?

Comment: You didn't get the .pem file from GoDaddy, surely? In the beginning you must have had a private key, which you didn't get from GoDaddy, and didn't send to them. Show *all* the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convert to PKC12/P12**

If the `my-file.pem` file is your private key (check the first line is 5 hyphens, BEGIN, optionally a word like RSA EC or ENCRYPTED, PRIVATE KEY, and 5 hyphens) then start with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my-file.crt -inkey my-file.pem -certfile bundle-g2-g1.crt -out my.p12
```

If the `my-file.key` file is your private key, the run the command below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my-file.crt -inkey my-file.key -certfile bundle-g2-g1.crt -out my-file.p12
```

**Note**:

You will be required to enter a password which you will need to save as it will be required by the application that wants to use the certificate.

**Convert to JKS**

Nearly all java programs since 2018 can actually use a PKCS12 instead of JKS for a keystore, but if this code really does need a JKS then do

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my-file.p12 -destkeystore my-file.jks -deststoretype jks 
# if using very old Java (below 8u40 or so) add -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

**Re-convert to PKCS12 from JKS**

The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my-file.jks -destkeystore my-file.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Mostly dupe (but somewhat updated from)
[Combined .pem certificate to truststore/keystore.jsk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179664/combined-pem-certificate-to-truststore-keystore-jsk)
[How to convert certificate from PEM to JKS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296312/convert-certificate-from-pem-into-jks)
[How do I generate X.509 certificate from key generated by openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032763/how-do-i-generate-x-509-certificate-from-key-generated-by-openssl) and more linked there
https://serverfault.com/questions/483465/import-of-pem-certificate-chain-and-key-to-java-keystore

Comment: Thanks for helping !